# Is there a way where i can get the decrypt password stored in the DB?

Tags: php, oracle, security, encryption

i'm trying to make a log in form where the password where encrypted in oracle DB, i can't decrypt the password in my select statement in php. when i put the correct password the error message pop out and when i try to put the encpryted password it proceeds to log in ,

```
$strSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, PASS_WORD FROM VW_SMF_USERS WHERE USER_ID = 
           '".trim($_POST['txtUseremail'])."' 
           AND PASS_WORD = '".trim($_POST['txtUserpassword'])."'";

$objParse = oci_parse ($objConnect, $strSQL);
oci_execute ($objParse,OCI_DEFAULT);
$objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse);
```

Comment: if you are developing from scratch, better to use the concept of digest, hash, salt. https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand your current scenario, you have hashed password in database, and you are querying user_input password direct to database, that is why application logged in with hash but not with plain text password.
You need to encrypt user_input password first in desired hash (md5,sha), 
example md5:

```
"SELECT USER_ID, PASS_WORD FROM VW_SMF_USERS WHERE USER_ID = 
           '".trim($_POST['txtUseremail'])."' 
           AND PASS_WORD = '".md5($_POST['txtUserpassword'])."'";
```